# Instantiation of array class of size unknown at compile time

Tags: c++, arrays, class, instantiation, dynamic-arrays

Below is a small script that prints the sums of the numbers 1 to n, for n = 1,...,20.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

int test(int n)
{
    array<int,n> myArray;

    for (int iii = 0; iii < n; iii++)
        myArray[iii] = iii+1;

    int nSum;

    for (int iii = 0; iii < n; iii++)
        nSum += myArray[iii];

    return nSum;
}


int main()
{
    for (int n = 1; n <= 20; n++)
        cout << test(n) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Of course, this won't compile:

```
Main.cpp: In function ‘int test(long unsigned int)’:
Main.cpp:9:13: error: ‘n’ is not a constant expression
  array<int,n> myArray;
         ^
Main.cpp:9:13: note: in template argument for type ‘long unsigned int’ 
Main.cpp:9:22: error: invalid type in declaration before ‘;’ token
  array<int,n> myArray;
                  ^
Main.cpp:11:26: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
  for (int iii = 0; iii < n; iii++)
                      ^
Main.cpp:12:14: error: invalid types ‘int[int]’ for array subscript
   myArray[iii] = iii+1;
          ^
Main.cpp:16:26: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
  for (int iii = 0; iii < n; iii++)
                      ^
Main.cpp:17:22: error: invalid types ‘int[int]’ for array subscript
   nSum += myArray[iii];
                  ^
make: *** [Main.o] Error 1
```

The problem seems to be (among other things) that `n` isn't a constant expression, and I get why that is a problem, but I have no idea how to solve it.

I know how to instantiate "regular" arrays with the new function, but I don't understand how it is possible with the array class.

How do I make the `test` function treat `n` as a constant?

Comment: That's what `std::vector` is for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have basically two options.

1. As you already mentioned, `std::array` needs a compile-time size. So make it known at compile-time! This can be done by converting it to a **template parameter**.

   Change

   ```
   int test(int n)
   {
     .
     .
     .
   }
   ```

   to

   ```
   template<int n>
   int test()
   {
     .
     .
     .
   }
   ```

   The problem is that it then has to be called with `test<n>()` instead of `test(n)` and this again requires the `n` in the caller code to be known at compile-time, too, which is not the case with a `for`-loop. If you know your loop's upper bound during compile-time (like in your current code snippet), it can be done, but it's a bit complicated. And if it's not known, i.e. a user input, you can't use this solution at all.

   So this is not a good option here.
2. Don't use `std::array` but a container type which doesn't require the size at compile-time but during **runtime**. A heap-allocated raw array (`new int[n]`), as you mentioned, is an option, but it's not very C++-ish. **Use `std::vector` instead**!

   For this, simply change

   ```
   array<int,n> myArray;
   ```

   to

   ```
   vector<int> myArray(n);
   ```

   PS. In the future, there probably will be [`std::dynarray` (proposed container type)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/dynarray) which fits exactly that purpose a bit better than `std::vector` currently does. It's reflecting the purpose of `new int[n]` where `n` is known at runtime but constant during the lifetime of the array, filling the gap between `std::array` and `std::vector`. Yet in almost all cases `std::vector` will do just fine!

Comment: This is a good answer, though you will probably need to clarify above that there currently is no way to resolve my issue, that I cannot treat `n` as a constant in any way.

Comment: Also, is the reason that this is impossible because templates are a "compiler trick"? Wouldn't I technically have to "compile" a new version of array at runtime (which is impossible) for my method to work?

Comment: After reading some trip reports from ISO C++ meeting in Rapperswil (June 2014) it is very unlikely that `dynarray` is going tto be added any time soon. There are just too many questions about it without a definitive answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) instead;

```
#include <vector>

vector<int> myArray (n); // n zero-initialized elements
```

use the [operator[]](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator[]/) like you are using the array.